# How to store user id after each incrementing button click

Tags: laravel

i made a simple button incrementing system the button works and  increments into the products table. But i want to keep record of who increments the button. I have a clicks table that takes in the product id and the customer id how do i store the id's after each click.

```
public function postClicks( $id){
    // This works increments
    $click = Product::FindorFail($id);
    $click->increment('clicks');
    $click->update();

    // this doesnt work
    $clicksave = new Click;
    $clicksave = $click;
    $clicksave->customer_id = Auth::guard('customer')->user()->id;
    $clicksave->save();
    // this is from the product table and clicks section

}
```

---

AJAX

```
<script>
$('.cardbutton-page').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var product = $(this).closest('#cardproduct');
    var product_id = product.attr('data-product-id');
    registerProductClicked(product_id);
});

function registerProductClicked(product_id){
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '/product/'+ product_id + '/click',
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         console.log(xhr.status);
         console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
     }
 });

}

</script>
```

---

```
Route::post('/product/{id}/click', 'ClicksController@postClicks');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure on your `Click` model that you have set `customer_id` to fillable.

i.e

```
Click extends Model
{

 protected $fillable = ['customer_id'];

}
```

and try `Click::create(['customer_id' => Auth::guard('customer')->user()->id]);`

Comment: Great! Glad to help.